# Add shortcut to website in right-click menu for chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to add a website shortcut in the right click menu when clicking on the icon for the google chrome extension.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access that context menu, only the one you get by right clicking on the page.